# mod_rewrite not sending Vary: Accept-Language when RewriteCond matches

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, mod-headers, vary

I have a rewrite rule which redirects to `/` if no `Accept-Language` header is present and someone attempts to visit `?lang=en`. It works fine, except for the headers returned. `Vary: Accept-Language` is missing from the response.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^$  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}         ^lang=en  
RewriteRule ^$                      http://www.example.com/?     [R=301,L]
```

The Apache documentation specifies:

> If a HTTP header is used in a condition this header is added to the Vary header of the response in case the condition evaluates to to true for the request. It is not added if the condition evaluates to false for the request.

The conditions are definitely matching and redirecting, so I don't understand why Apache isn't adding the language vary. One can see why this would be a real problem if a proxy were to cache that `?lang=en` and always redirect to `/` regardless of the Accept-Language header sent.

Comment: +1 Didn’t know that the header field is (intended to be) automatically added to *Vary*.

Comment: But it does work as expected for me. What Apache version are you using and how do you test it?

Comment: Is `Accept-Language` sent and blank, or not sent at all?

Comment: The rewrite works fine for me, but I get no Vary: Accept-Language, only Vary: Accept-Encoding, to clarify. Tested with Fiddler and web-sniffer.net. Apache 2.2.14. I'll try to reproduce on a clean Apache install on another box, though I did try without a redirect and had no luck.

Comment: Hmm...`mod_rewrite` correctly sets the header, but it gets clobbered somewhere before Apache sends the response. Now, to just figure out where that happens...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After peeking into the seedy underbelly of Apache's request handling system, it turns out that the documentation is somewhat misleading...But before I get into the explanation, from what I can tell you're at the mercy of Apache on this one.

#### The Client Problem

First, the header name will not be added to the **Vary** response header if it is not sent by the client. This is due to how `mod_rewrite` constructs the value for that header [internally](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/branches/2.2.x/modules/mappers/mod_rewrite.c).

It looks up the header by name using [`apr_table_get()`](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/trunk/group__apr__tables.html#g4db13e3915c6b9a3142b175d4c15d915), the request's header table, and the name that you provided:

```
const char *val = apr_table_get(ctx->r->headers_in, name);
```

If `name` is not a key in the table, this function will return `NULL`. This is a problem, because immediately after this is a check against `val`:

```
if (val) {
   // Set the structure member ctx->vary_this
}
```

`ctx->vary_this` is used on a per-`RewriteCond` basis to accumulate header names that should be assembled into the final **Vary** header*. Since no assignment or appending will occur if there is no value, a referenced (but not sent) header will never appear in `Vary`. The documentation doesn't explicitly state this, so it may or may not have been what you expected.

<sup>*As an aside, the `NV` (no vary) flag and ignore-on-failure functionality is implemented by setting `ctx->vary_this` to `NULL`, preventing its addition to the response header.</sup>

However, it's possible that you sent **Accept-Language**, but it was blank. In this case, the empty string will pass the above check, and the header name will be added to **Vary** by `mod_rewrite` from what's described above. Keeping this in mind, I used the following request to diagnose what was going on:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: 
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 129.168.0.123
```

This doesn't work either, but why? `mod_rewrite` definitely sets the headers when the rule and condition match (`ctx->vary` is an aggregate of `ctx->vary_this` across all checked conditions):

```
if (ctx->vary) {
    apr_table_merge(r->headers_out, "Vary", ctx->vary);
}
```

This can be verified with a log statement, and `r->headers_out` *is* the variable used when generating the response headers. Given something is definitely going wrong though, there must be trouble after the rules are executed.

#### The .htaccess Problem

Currently, you appear to be defining your rules in `.htaccess`, or a `<Directory>` section. This means that `mod_rewrite` is operating in Apache's fixup phase, and the mechanism it uses to actually perform rewrites here is very messy. Let's assume for a second there's no external redirection, since you had problem a even without it (and I'll get to the issue with the redirect later).

After you perform a rewrite, it's far too late in the request processing for the module to actually map to a file. What it does instead is assign itself as the request's "content" handler and when the request reaches that point, it performs a call to `ap_internal_redirect()`. This leads to the creation of a new request object, one that does not contain the `headers_out` table from the original.

Assuming that `mod_rewrite` causes no further redirects, the response is generated from the *new* request object, which will never have the appropriate (original) headers assigned to it. It is possible to get around this by working in a per-server context (in the main configuration or in a `<VirtualHost>`), but...

#### The Redirect Problem

Unfortunately, it turns out that it's largely irrelevant anyway, since even if we do use `mod_rewrite` in a server context, the path the response takes in the event of a redirect still causes the headers that the module set to be tossed out.

When the request is received by Apache, through a chain of function calls it makes its way to `ap_process_request()`. This in turn calls `ap_process_request_internal()`, where the bulk of the important request parsing steps occur (including the invocation of `mod_rewrite`). It returns an integer status code, which in the case of your redirect happens to be set to 301.

Most requests return `OK` (which has a value of 0), leading immediately to `ap_finalize_request_protocol()`. However, that's [not the case here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/branches/2.2.x/modules/http/http_request.c):

```
if (access_status == OK) {
    ap_finalize_request_protocol(r);
}
else {
    r->status = HTTP_OK;
    ap_die(access_status, r);
}
```

`ap_die()` does some additional manipulation (like returning the response code back to 301), and in this particular case ends with a call to `ap_send_error_response()`.

Luckily, this is finally root of the problem. Though it might seem like it, things are not "assbackwards", and this causes the destruction of the original headers. There's even a comment about it [in the source](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/branches/2.2.x/modules/http/http_protocol.c):

```
if (!r->assbackwards) {
    apr_table_t *tmp = r->headers_out;

    /* For all HTTP/1.x responses for which we generate the message,
     * we need to avoid inheriting the "normal status" header fields
     * that may have been set by the request handler before the
     * error or redirect, except for Location on external redirects.
     */
    r->headers_out = r->err_headers_out;
    r->err_headers_out = tmp;
    apr_table_clear(r->err_headers_out);

    if (ap_is_HTTP_REDIRECT(status) || (status == HTTP_CREATED)) {
        if ((location != NULL) && *location) {
            apr_table_setn(r->headers_out, "Location", location);
        }
        //...
    }
//...
}
```

Take note that `r->headers_out` is replaced, and the original table is cleared. That table had all of the information that was expected to show up in the response, so now it is lost.

#### Conclusion

If you don't redirect and you define the rules in a per-server context, everything does seem to work correctly. However, this is not what you want. I can see a potential workaround, but I'm not sure if it would be acceptable, not to mention the need to recompile the server.

As for the `Vary: Accept-Encoding`, I can only assume it comes from a different module that behaves in a way that allows the header to sneak through. I'm also not sure why [Gumbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53114/gumbo) didn't have an issue when trying it.

For reference, I was looking at the 2.2.14 and [2.2 trunk source code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/branches/2.2.x/), and I was modifying and running Apache 2.2.15. There doesn't appear to be any significant differences between the versions in the related code sections.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try something like the following as a workaround:

```
<LocationMatch "^.*lang\=">
    Header onsuccess merge Vary "Accept-Language"
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: You would need to use the `always` condition (as opposed to `onsuccess`) in order to set this header on the redirect itself. However, the `<LocationMatch>` directive matches against the URL-path only, not the query string, so this will never match anyway, and the header is never set. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66298143/369434) for a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

To specifically set the `Vary: Accept-Language` HTTP response header on the *redirect* response *only* (which is what's expected here), you would need to set an environment variable (eg. `VARY_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`) as part of the redirect rule and use this to set the header conditionally with the `Header` directive.

You also need to use the `always` *condition* (as opposed to the default `onsuccess`) with the `Header` directive in order to set this on the 3xx response (ie. non-200 reponses).

For example:

```
# Redirect requests that have an empty Accept-Language header and "lang=en" is present
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^$  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=en  
RewriteRule ^$ /? [E=VARY_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE:1,R=301,L]

# Set/Merge "Vary" header on Accept-Language redirect
Header always merge Vary "Accept-Language" env=VARY_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE
```

HOWEVER, the `Vary` header shouldn't only be set on the redirect response (when the `Accept-Language` header is empty), it needs to be set on all responses to requests for `/?lang=en`, regardless of what the `Accept-Language` HTTP request header is actually set to. So, relying on Apache to set this header using only the redirect would not be sufficient anyway (even if it did set the header on the response as initially expected).

In order to set the appropriate `Vary` header on all responses to requests for `/?lang=en`, including the redirect then do it like this:

```
# Set env var if "/?lang=en" is requested
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=en  
RewriteRule ^$ - [E=VARY_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE:1]

# Redirect requests that have an empty Accept-Language header and "lang=en" is present
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^$  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=en  
RewriteRule ^$ /? [R=301,L]

# Set/Merge "Vary" header on all responses from "/?lang=en"
Header always merge Vary "Accept-Language" env=VARY_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE
```

Note, however, that if you have additional internal rewrite directives that cause the rewrite engine to start over then the env var `VARY_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` is renamed to `REDIRECT_VARY_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` and the above `Header` directive will not be successful. You'll probably need an additional directive to handle this. For example:

```
Header always merge Vary "Accept-Language" env=REDIRECT_VARY_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE
```